# Twig template variable not displaying value

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I have a Twig template for a custom block. My custom module is establishing what template is used like so

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array('mymodule' =>
        array(
            'variables' => array(
                'header-title' => 'Default Title',
                'header-size' => 'h1'
                ), 
                'template' => 'block--HeaderText'
            )
        );
}
```

and my custom block contains.

```
public function build() {
    return array(
        '#theme' => 'mymodule',
        '#title' => '',
        '#header-title' => $this->configuration['label'],
        '#header-size' => $this->configuration['header-size-submit'],
        );
}
```

And in my block--HeaderText.html.twig I have

```
<h2>{{ header-title }}</h2> This is a test {{ header-size }}
{{ dump() }}
```

However header-title and header-size both output 0. But using the dump() function in the template shows that the actual variables are available some how.

The dump() produces

```
array(15) { ["header-title"]=> string(19) "Header Textsdfgsdfg" ["header-size"]=> string(2) "h4"...
```

Yet {{ header-title }} just results in 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that Drupal didn't like that the variable names had hyphens in them. 
When switching from header-text to header_text it worked fine.